# jquery stopPropagation stopped ajax get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with clickable rows and ajax link at the most right column.
When I clicked on the link in the row, the row clicked event get fired as well.

In order to stopped the event propagation, I've used stopPropagation to stop the row clicked event firing. However the ajax get became a normal HTML get, which result in loading a new page.

How can I have the AJAX get work together with stop propagation?

Thanks.

Below are my codes:

```
<tr data-id="@user.UserId" style="cursor:pointer">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.LastLogin)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = user.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
           {
               HttpMethod = "GET",
               OnSuccess = "getModalSuccess"
           }) |
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Reset password", "ResetPassword", new { id = user.UserId }, new AjaxOptions
           {
               HttpMethod = "GET",
               OnSuccess = "getModalSuccess"
           })
            </td>
        </tr>

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#user-list > tbody > tr').click(function () {
            var url = "/Account/Edit/" + $(this).data('id');
            $.get(url, getModalSuccess);
        });

        // To stop propagation to parent, which causes event above fired
        $('#user-list > tbody > tr > td > a').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });

    function getModalSuccess(data) {
        $('#modal-container').html(data);
        $('#modal-dialog').modal('show');
        $('form').removeData('validator');
        $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
        $('form').validate();
    }
</script>
```

Generated HTML

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-success="getModalSuccess" href="/Account/Delete/b9b70187-1188-4398-96f7-cda32e67b14a">Delete</a>
```

Comment: What markup is being generated? It sounds like you're getting a form submission when you click the link, so maybe try returning false which combines stopPropagation and preventDefault?

Comment: On the <a> tag event handler, you likely need **e.preventDefault()** -stopping the  "which result in loading a new page"

Comment: @kinakuta added generated HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for myself.
Instead of placing the actual link in href of the anchors, I handle the click event, and from there using jquery .get() and stopPropagation(). Codes below

```
 <a href="#" data-url='/Account/Delete/@user.UserId'>Test</a>
 $('#user-list > tbody > tr > td > a').click(function (e) {
     var url = $(this).data('url');
     $.get(url, getModalSuccess);
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, last time I checked, unobtrusive Ajax used the following construct to bind on load.

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

This construct is bound to `document` event. In other words, the event bubbles up to the document, and only then the ajax happens. By calling `e.stopPropagation();` you explicitly stop the bubbling of the event up to the document where the ajax making handler is attached, so it just don't get executed.