# Keeping drop down open, blocking AJAX (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am keeping a bootstrap drop down open when the user clicks the content of the dropdown, otherwise it should be hidden ( e.g. on outside click and when the button is pressed again)

This is working in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sK56j/

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown > ul').on({
        "click": function() {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

However, I am adding an ajax link (asp.net mvc) into the dropdown, when clicked the ajax event is being blocked.

How can I achieve the above without blocking all javascript events?

Here's a quick paint masterpiece for what I am trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRUCO.jpg

Thanks

EDIT:

AJAX Link Code

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("X", 
                 "Action", "Controller", 
                  new { <route values> }, new AjaxOptions { 
                               HttpMethod = "POST", 
                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                               UpdateTargetId = "element-id" }, 
                  new { <html attributes> })
```

http:// msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do… are you trying to remove a row and have the page update via ajax? Or are you trying to add a new element? Or remove a row on click?

Comment: See above edit. There will be a list in the drop down and the user removes entries one by one. The the list will be 'refreshed' on each removal via ajax. Does that make sense?
So the row is removed, by the list being refreshed. The action method on the controller marks the entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'm finally starting to understand the problem. As far as I can see, there are multiple options.

You could either use the suggestions from the link you posted in the comments, or you could overwrite the bootstrap click-to-close event with a custom one. But I unfortunately don't see a clean solution (there might be one though).

Comment: I basically don't want the drop down to disappear unless you click outside it or on the button again. I can't use event.preventDefault() as the drop down contains links I still want to click

Comment: Where is the part of the code that makes the dropdown disappear?

Comment: its done automatically by bootstrap. see: 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Comment: Then try `event.stopPropagation();` instead. This should stop the event from bubbling up to higher events.

Comment: If I use that, it stops my ajax button in the dropdown from working?
Perhaps I have approached this wrong?

Comment: Maybe it works if its mapped directly to the a element in the dropdown (see edit).

Comment: im basically getting this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931677/jquery-stoppropagation-stopped-ajax-get

event.stopPropagation is turning my ajax get into a normal get. When the button of the drop down item is pressed, it needs to go off to my controller, recreate the list (partial view) and replace the old one